# Cyclic redirection in htaccess: HTTPS -> HTTP rule is ignored

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https, openshift, haproxy

**PART I**

I have had the following rewrite rules in htaccess file (on an OpehShift server):

```
RewriteEngine on

# Must NOT be SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =https
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [or]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/user/login
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/user/register
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/user/profile
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/user/captcha
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [last,redirect=permanent]

# MUST be SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !=https
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/user/login [or]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/user/register [or]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/user/captcha [or]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/user/profile
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [last]

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

The purpose is to have some paths processed via SSL, while all the others should be acessible via plain http. Initially it was a challenge to setup such config, but it was eventually solved - you may find its history on [OpenShift forums](https://forums.openshift.com/forcing-https-on-certain-urls-with-modrewrite-makes-infinite-redirection).

This worked fine till some moment in past (perhaps some OpenShift update), when it started cyclic looping on https pages: for example, when a user is on his profile page (with `https`) and clicks a link for a page outside the secure paths it tries to redirect to `https`, when again and again.

According to the rules, they should change `https` to `http` if it's not login, register, profile or captcha pages, but this does not happen anymore. What can be the problem? Thanks in advance.

**PART II**

Despite the fact that I accepted @anubhava answer (because this seems to be Apache's problem not mine, as he supposed after hours of invaluable debugging), I'm still struggling with the issue, and any further solutions/workarounds are highly welcomed.

Meanwhile the problem is pinpointed down to the following code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [env=ps:https]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [env=ps:http]

# known public pages
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/site/page/about
RewriteRule (.*) %{ENV:ps}://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1?ps=%{ENV:ps}&step=1 [last,redirect=permanent]
```

Now when I go to the about page, I got the following http headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Thu, 27 Nov 2014 15:07:27 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat)
Location: https://mydomain.rhcloud.com/site/page/about?ps=http&step=1
Content-Length: 385
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Accept-Ranges: none
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=99
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Please note that `Location` has `https` proto, yet `ps` parameter is outputted as `http` (as expected). How this can be if both values are taken from `ps` variable? It looks weird IMHO.

To put it shortly: **redirections from https to http do not work on OpenShift servers**. Despite the rule saying that protocol should be `http` server sends out `https` - hence cyclic redirections.

**PART III**

Perhaps I should mention that the OpenShift site uses HAProxy as a frontend. Its config does not contain any ssl specific settings. But I have found [this related answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/481801/haproxy-redirects-and-matching-based-off-uri), where one may read:

> Finally you're not going **to be able to actually redirect people away from an HTTPS connection**, this is considered insecure and is **not supported**.

So, can it be that HAProxy does always implicitly override protocol to `https` for redirections made from secured pages? How to workaround this then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `REQUEST_URI` use `THE_REQUEST` since you're using a front controller.

```
RewriteEngine on

# Must NOT be SSL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =https
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+user/(login|register|profile|captcha) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

# MUST be SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !=https
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+user/(login|register|profile|captcha) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but your exact code broke CSS styles. I'll try to use THE_REQUEST only.

Comment: Using `THE_REQUEST` instead `REQUST_URI` in my original code does not solve infinite redictedtions issue.

Comment: ok see updated rules to take care of css issue. If it is causing redirect loop then open your `https://domain.com/user/profile` URL in Chrome Dev tool or Firebug and see what redirects you get in the `Net` tab.

Comment: It preserves styles now, but when a user clicks to the home link (`/` address) it gets main site page with `https` which is incorrect. Also all other public pages (for example `/site/page/about`) are trying to show with `https` and fail with cyclic redirection.

Comment: Looping persists on public pages after leaving a secure page, as I mentioned in the comment above.

Comment: [let's discuss this in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65709/discussion-between-anubhava-and-stan)

Comment: thank you for the help in the chat. as we found out openshift gears seem ignoring https value or not passing it to php somehow

Comment: OpenShift support did not respond, so I made a clumsy workaround. Please find details in my answer if you're interested in.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I managed to build a workaround, though I don't think it's elegant. If you know another way, please let me know. I mean a way - working in OpenShift environment.

The solution is to use `.htaccess` for handling only one way redirections: from `http` to `https`. Redirections from `https` to `http` are handled by client-side code which instructs browser to reload page under different scheme.

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on

# MUST be SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+user/(login|register|profile|captcha)
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302,NE]

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php 
RewriteRule . index.php
```

**index.php**

```
...
require('switchhttp.php');
...
```

**switchhttp.php**

```
<?
function redirect_url($url)
{
  ?>
  <script>
  window.location.href="<? echo $url; ?>";
  </script>
  <?
}

$urls = array("/user/login", "/user/register", "/user/captcha", "/user/profile");
$url = rawurldecode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

if(!in_array($url, $urls) && isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']))
{
  redirect_url("http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]");
  exit;
}
?>
```

This worked for me.

<sub>Also, I should probably warn those of you who may be interested that OpenShift gears may accidentally fall into a "caching state" so to speak (perhaps this relates to HAProxy especially). In such cases updating files on the gears does not take effect - your browser, whether it's cleared cache or not, and even absolutely new connected clients receive old pages. Very frustrating for debugging. The only way I have found to remedy this problem so far is to restart your gear.</sub>

Comment: Om my God, you had to take PHP route to get it done. Hope openshift responds. +1 for the effort

Comment: Strangely enough, but Wikipedia seems using the same method last months: when I open an article first time after navigating from say Google's search results, I see briefly its `http` version, then the page is automatically reloaded under `https`.

Comment: OpenShift support has just confirmed my suggestion that all technical questions from free plan users should be posted here on StackOverflow.

Comment: That's bizarre, obviously their support guys don't know anything.